# How do you read arguments passed to a native kernel?

Tags: opencl

I have a native kernel setup but I don't know how to convert its void* argument into anything useful. In the native kernel of this snippet, how would I get the int (7) or the int[] (16 ints set to 0)?

```
void __stdcall nativeKernel(void * args) 
{
    int a1 = (*(int*)args);
    cout << "a1-->: "<< a1 << endl; // gibberish
}


void kernelCaller() 
{
    const int dim1Size = 16;
    int dim1[dim1Size] = {};

    cl_int status = 0;

    cl_mem mem_d1 = clCreateBuffer(*context, 0, sizeof(int)*dim1Size, NULL, &status);
    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(*queue, mem_d1, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int)*dim1Size, dim1, 0, NULL, NULL);

    const void* args[2] = {(void*)7, NULL}; 
    cl_mem mem_list[1] = {mem_d1};
    const void* args_mem_loc[1] = {&args[1]};

    cl_event run;
    status = clEnqueueNativeKernel(*queue, nativeKernel, args, 2, 1, mem_list, args_mem_loc, 0, NULL, &run);
    status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(*queue, mem_d1, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int)*dim1Size, dim1, 1, &run, NULL);

    for(auto i = 0; i != dim1Size; i++)
        cout << dim1[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of playing hard with `void*` i would like to suggest to use `struct`
create your parameter structure like:

```
struct myparams{
  int a
  int a[3];
};
```

and then create and fill one `struct myparams` in your program and pass its address to the kernelcaller

```
struct myparams params;
params.a=3;

status = clEnqueueNativeKernel(*queue, nativeKernel, (void*)&params, 2, 1, mem_list, args_mem_loc, 0, NULL, &run);
```

and in the `nativeKernel` just unbox the `void*` into your parameter struct:

```
struct myparams *params=(myparams*)args;
```

beware: in the example above i passed a pointer of the stack...you might not want that ;)